# Are there any slavic or romance languages/dialects with allophonic aspirated consonants?

Tags: phonology

I know a lot of slavic and romance languages don't aspirate their consonants at all, but are there any languages from these two subgroups of languages that do use aspiration as a feature of consonants?

Comment: I remember that some dialects of Spanish (or perhaps it was some other Iberian romance language) aspirate voiceless consonants after /s/ in onset consonant sequences, but I will have to confirm.

Comment: I think that  /t/, /p/, and /k/ are often aspirated in French at the end of words.

Comment: In my native spanish dialect there is indeed such an allophony for velar consonants. I do not believe it happens in other cases (in spanish).  ex: bosque --> \ˈboχkʰe\.  This is never phonemic (I know you asked about allophones, but just to be clear).

Comment: What is the dialect of Spanish that you speak? it looks very interesting.